# Is the form of the verb right?

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural, third-person-singular

"France **have** won their second World Cup title."

Why is it have and not **has**? France isn't plural, right?

Comment: Discussed in other questions such as https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183003/can-the-name-of-a-country-be-considered-a-plural-noun-as-a-collective-of-e-g-i

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"France **have** won **their** second World Cup title."

or

"France **has** won **its** second World Cup title."

For correct grammar, you must match the pronoun to the verb.

---

**France have won **their** second World Cup title**

This can mean, "The people of France have won ..."

or

"The members of the French team have won ..."

---

**France **has** won **its** second World Cup title.**

This means that the nation "France" has won.

or

The team "France" has won.